# Calling Delete rest API issue

Tags: c#, api, blazor

I'm trying to delete an item from a calendar but I feel the call to the API is incorrect.

I'm getting a 404 status code & this error:

> System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.DeleteFromJsonAsyncCore[T](Task`1 taskResponse, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken

Below is my client code:

```
async Task DeleteAppointment(SchedulerDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    UvwHolidayPlanner holidayPlannerItem = e.Item as UvwHolidayPlanner;

    holidayPlanner.Pk = holidayPlannerItem.Pk;

    await http.CreateClient("ClientSettings").DeleteFromJsonAsync<UvwHolidayPlanner>($"{_URL}/api/HolidayPlannerOperations/DeleteHolidayPlanner/{holidayPlanner.Pk}");

    HolidayPlanners = (await http.CreateClient("ClientSettings").GetFromJsonAsync<List<UvwHolidayPlanner>>($"{_URL}/api/lookup/HolidayPlanner"))
    .OrderBy(t => t.Title)
    .ToList();

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Below is my API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HolidayPlannerOperationsController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("DeleteHolidayPlanner/{PK}")]
    public void Delete(int PK)
    {
        string SQLSTE = "EXEC [dbo].[usp_DeleteHolidayPlanner] @PK";
        using (var context = new TestAppContext())
        {
            List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>
            {
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@PK", Value = PK },
            };

            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(SQLSTE, param);
        }
    }
}
```

After doing as advised at the bottom and changing the route from [Route("DeleteHolidayPlanner")] to [Route("DeleteHolidayPlanner/{PK}")]

I'm now getting the below error message:

> Error: System.Text.Json.JsonException: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
>
> ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: The input does not contain
> any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token,
> when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Comment: remove `/api/HolidayPlannerOperations` part of your route as per your route attribute. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#adding-route-attributes. I recommend using the network tab of your browser to see whats really being called. Your Http client should already be configured with a base address and your should only need a relative path as a parameter.

Comment: @BrianParker This worked. Now getting an issue: Error: System.Text.Json.JsonException: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Comment: @BrianParker I'm unsure if it is controller it seems to do everything i want it to do & does execute my stored procedure so the appointment is deleted. The client seems to break though

Comment: Your call `DeleteFromJsonAsync<UvwHolidayPlanner>` is expecting a return type of `UvwHolidayPlanner` your controller method is void. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.deletefromjsonasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-json-httpclientjsonextensions-deletefromjsonasync-1(system-net-http-httpclient-system-string-system-text-json-serialization-metadata-jsontypeinfo((-0))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)

Comment: @BrianParker Even changing it to an async task i still get same error

Comment: It not only needs to be Async it needs to return the deleted item wich in your case is a `UvwHolidayPlanner`   so `Task<UvwHolidayPlanner>` or if you dont want to go Async just `public UvwHolidayPlanner Delete(int PK)` The other option is dont use `DeleteFromJsonAsync<UvwHolidayPlanner>` just `DeleteFromJsonAsync` this should work with a void return type. I normally always use async with a return type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251140/discussion-between-bgcode-and-brian-parker).